# Sorting a list of lists with itertools imap in Python

Tags: python, sorting, python-itertools

I'm wondering what's happening when I execute this code and also if there is a better way to accomplish the same task. Is a list of lists being made in memory to preform the sort, and then bar is assigned to be an iterator of foo.values()? Or possibly foo.values() is sorted in the allotted dictionary memory space (seems unlikely)?

Imagine the first value in the list, the integer, refers to a line number in a file. I want to open the file and update only the lines referenced in the foo.values() lists with the rest of the data in the list (EG update line 1 with strings '123' and '097').

```
from itertools import imap

>>> foo = {'2134':[1, '123', '097'], '6543543':[3, '1'], '12315':[2, '454']}
>>> bar = imap([].sort(), foo.values())
```

Thanks~

Comment: What is the output you are after? It's not clear to me from the question. `list(bar)` gives me `[([1, '123', '097'],), ([2, '454'],), ([3, '1'],)]` - is this the output you want and are looking for a different way to get?

Comment: Are you really asking "what does this code do", or are you asking for help trying to actually accomplish something? If the latter, please explain what you're trying to do, because from what you've written, all we can do is guess.

Comment: Yes, that's the output I am after. Where the outer list has inner lists sorted by the inner list's first value (the line number).

Comment: Would >>> bar = iter(foo.values().sort()) be more appropriate?

Comment: @bfb: The output is exactly the same as `list(bar.items())`. Nothing is being sorted at all.

Comment: @bfb: No, that wouldn't be appropriate either. `foo.values().sort()` makes a list of the values, sorts that list, releases the sorted list, and returns `None`. Then you're calling `iter(None)`.

Comment: Yes, more like values = foo.values(); sorted_values = values.sort(); sorted_values_it = iter(sorted_values); but that requires making a copy. How can the copy be avoided?

Comment: @bfb: No, `values.sort()` sorts `values` in-place and returns `None`; it doesn't copy anything. And I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that `iter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you're passing `[].sort()`, which is just `None`, as the first argument to `imap`, meaning it's doing nothing at all. As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) explain: "If function is set to None, then imap() returns the arguments as a tuple."

To pass a callable to a higher-order function like `imap`, you have to pass the callable itself, not call it and pass the result.

Plus, you don't want `[].sort` here; that's a callable with no arguments that just sorts an empty list, which is useless.

You probably wanted `list.sort`, the unbound method, which is a callable with one argument that will sort whatever list it's given.

---

So, if you did that, what would happen is that you'd creating an iterator that, if you iterated it, would generate a bunch of `None` values and, as a side effect, sort each list in `foo.values()`. No new lists would be created anywhere, because `list.sort` mutates the list in-place and returns `None`.

But since you don't ever iterate it anyway, it hardly matters what you put into `imap`; what it actually does is effectively nothing.

---

Generally, abusing `map`/`imap`/comprehensions/etc. for side-effects of the expressions is a bad idea. An iterator that generates useless values, but that you have to iterate anyway, is a recipe for confusion at best.

The simple thing to do here is to just use a loop:

```
for value in foo.values():
    value.sort()
```

Or, instead of sorting in-place, generate new sorted values:

```
bar = imap(sorted, foo.values())
```

Now, as you iterate `bar`, each list will be sorted *and given to you*, so you can use it. If you iterate this, it *will* generate a sorted list in memory for each list… but only one will ever be alive at a time (unless you explicitly stash them somewhere).

Comment: bar = imap(sorted, foo.values()) is close, but I need to sort the outer list by the first value of the inner list.

Comment: Aha, no mapping necessary. Confused myself... The sort operation only has to be applied once, not to each element of the iterable. >>> bar = iter(sorted(foo.values())) suits my fancy. Though still not sure what's happening in memory here. Thanks much.

Comment: @bfb: What's happening in memory is that `foo.values()` makes a new list in-memory with the values from `foo`, then `sorted()` makes a new list in-memory with the sorted values from that first list. But why do you care so much about what's happening in memory? Get your code working first, then identify problems to optimize, then optimize them; if you just want to use as little memory as possible and don't care about the right answer, you can just use `pass` for that…